# style div inside table

Tags: css-float

I have the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.campo {
  text-align : right;
  float : left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr style="text-decoration:line-through;">
      <td>
        <div class="campo">campo1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="campo">campo2</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not get to apply the style to tr. If I remove the float property, no problem. 
because?
http://jsfiddle.net/ZxQjE/

Answer (score 0):

According to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=403526, the following applies to **text-decoration**:

> It is not, however, further propagated to floating and absolutely positioned
>    descendants, nor to the contents of 'inline-table' and 'inline-block'
>    descendants.

Apparently it is by design.